# Please, find a Decent Audio Driver for Lenovo Y50-70 in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (has JBL Speakers, but Linux unable to use max potential)

Tags: drivers, sound, lenovo, speakers

I'm used to the sound my laptop produces when it's running on Windows. Ubuntu has Volume Exceed, which just horribly distorts the Audio. Audio works perfectly in Windows. Please tell me how to utilize Maximum Quality and Quantity of the Speakers given by Lenovo when running Ubuntu 14.04(LTS). TIA :D

Comment: Volume Exceed doesn't work to horribly well with any speakers.  Windows probably just doesn't make it exceed as much.  Try turning down the volume a tad.

Comment: The Sub-Woofer isn't being used to its best, so good percentage of the volume is pressurizing the front speakers. That makes screechy and distorted sound, which is not healthy for any kind of speakers. Hope you understand.

Answer (score 2):

it seems that for ubuntu subwoofer doesn’t work out of the box, I got my Y50-70 subwoffer working by changing two config files:

/etc/pulse/default.pa
 add this line at the end: `load-module module-combine channels=6 channel_map=front-left,front-right,lfe`

/etc/pulse/deamon.conf
 modify `; enable-lfe-remixing = no` to `enable-lfe-remixing = yes` (remvoe the ';' to uncomment the line)

references:
  http://www.andreagrandi.it/2013/06/22/how-to-make-subwoofer-work-in-ubuntu/

This should have this sorted for you, if later you have any issues with directly controlling the subwoofer volume, install "pavucontrol".

Comment: The parameter channels=6 doesn't work for my Y50-70. Use channels=3 instead.